# What does the preposition "in" in "I’m looking for a sweater in a size medium" mean?

Tags: meaning, prepositions

We can say:

> 1. The dress is a size 12.
> 2. The dress is in a size 12.
> 3. The dress comes in a size 12.
> 4. We have this dress in a size 12.

My question is:

What does the preposition "**in**" in "**I’m looking for a sweater in a size medium**" mean?

Comment: Your question is missing a word.  You can say "what does (it) *mean*?", or What does it *do*?".  But you need a main verb; the word "does" is the helping verb not the main verb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an article of clothing, or any object, can be produced with variations in a specific characteristic, we say it is produced 'in' those variations.

> Clothing is made in different sizes
>   Paint is made in different colors
>   Doorknobs are manufactured in aluminum, steel and brass

So when we are talking about one instance of such an object we can also say that it is in a specific one of its variations.

> A dress in (a) size 12
>   An exterior paint in blue
>   A round doorknob in brass

In the example, 'We have this dress in a size 12', the speaker is referring to the model or style of the dress. To express the full idea explicitly you could say

> This dress model is made in different sizes. We have a dress that is in this model that was made in size 12.

(Dresses are made in different models and each model is made in different sizes!)

When talking about a specific instance of a dress, or other object that comes in variations, it is more clear to use your first example instead of your second, in order to avoid confusing the individual dress that is a size 12 with the model of dress that comes in many different sizes.

This is an idiomatic usage of the word 'in' that doesn't have a clear intuitive relationship to other uses of the word, which is why it's so confusing and hard to explain.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those things that's pretty hard to explain without just repeating the word you're trying to define, but I guess that's true for a lot of prepositions.

#1 and #2 mean the same thing: It's a size 12 dress. (The second one is rarer though.)

The next two (#3 and #4) are very similar. Pragmatically, in these sentences "the dress" and "this dress" don't refer to size 12 dresses. Instead, #3 means that they make size 12 dresses of the same style and color as the one that's being referred to, but it doesn't say if they have any in stock. #4 is very similar, but they have a size 12 dress of that type in stock.

"I’m looking for a sweater in a size medium" just means "I’m looking for a medium sweater".

---

Probably an easier way to think about it is to remember that this expression can also be used materials, which makes a bit more sense conceptually:

- A sweater in wool
- A statue in gold